# npm start giving errors on tsc && concurrently

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, typescript-typings, tsc

I've been trying to run npm start and I keep getting the following errors...

```
19 error node v4.2.0
20 error npm  v3.10.5
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error resume-editor@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the resume-editor@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the resume-editor package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs resume-editor
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls resume-editor
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've tried the following:
npm install tsc (& the latest version)
npm install --save typings 
typings install
npm install concurrently
npm install
npm run typings
npm run tsc (errors here)

Nothing seems to get npm start to work. 
What's making this even more confusing is the fact that everything was running perfectly up until I exited out and tried to run node server.js.
Then once I tried to switch back to npm start I've been getting these errors ever since.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "resume-editor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "body-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "method-override": "^2.1.3",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.12",
    "morgan": "^1.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "tsc": "^1.20150623.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

P.S: I have the latest versions of both node and npm.

Comment: What does the script section of your package.json look like?

Comment: Was there an error message before this log output? Probably you have an error in a TypeScript file.

Comment: @DaveV just added it to the original post

Answer (score 1):

you've install a package called TSC, it's probably colliding with the command line from the typescript package `tsc`.  Try uninstalling the TSC package and re-running

Comment: Uninstall TSC and then try run npm start? Yea I tried that still the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `typescript` globally.

`npm install -g typescript`

Comment: that was going to be my next recommendation, but it shouldn't be required, since he has the "tsc": "tsc" in the scripts...

Comment: @DaveV I don't believe that the terminal has access to local installs though

Comment: Doing it that way it does, I don't know NPM well enough to explain why, but it works.  He's doing it the exact way Angular has their quickstart setup...so I'm not sure why it's failing

Comment: Is there any more to the error message?  the first few lines maybe?  I'm reaching here, I'm at a loss

Comment: @DaveV no that's really just all that comes up. It's weird because it was literally just working right before I ran node server.js

Comment: @MrManny did you try reinstalling `typescript`?

Comment: @MrManny what about the two different versions of concurrently you have listed between devDependencies and dependencies?  it's the same Major version, so I wouldn't think it would mess with it...but???

Honestly, at this point, I would clean up the `package.json` and blow away typings and node_modules and just do a `npm install` and `npm start` again...

Comment: @DaveV I'll give that a try, hopefully that works because I've tried everything else. Just npm uninstall right?

Comment: I typically just delete the folders

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no spaces in the path to the root of your project. Rename ancestor directories to have no white spaces.